# Verb подписываться vs выписать

Tags: словоупотребление

In a magazine on an advertising page asking readers to subscribe the word *подписываться* was used. In a beginners' Russian textbook I saw the word *выписать* for the same thing. Are both correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Выписать** strictly refers to printed periodicals delivered by regular mail, and, as such, is a little outdated now. Also, as far as I remember from my childhood when it was much more common to subscribe to things by mail, **выписывать газету/журнал** referred to *being* a subscriber (i.e. regularly receiving the publication), whereas the *action* of subscribing (as in filling in the form and paying at the post office) was **подписаться**, which transitioned quite naturally into online usage. **Выписывать**, on the other hand, didn't make it to electronic mailing lists; you say **я подписан на эту рассылку**, never *я выписываю эту рассылку*.

Comment: small addition: if it is not about periodicals, **подписаться** and **выписать** will have totally different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are, the contexts they are used in differ and their form affects the meaning

`выписывать` means both `to set up a subscription` and `be a regular subscriber`
`выписать` only means `to set up a subscription` as does `подписаться/подписываться`

`подписаться/подписываться` requires preposition `на`+ Accusative

If there's a subscription campaign going on the most likely verb would be `подписаться`

If it's a private personal affair both are applicable, while `подписаться` is more formal and doesn't go with every word denoting a periodical

> Я подписался на это издание

is stylistically preferable over

> Я выписал это издание

`издание` is a broad generic term

they're interchangeable however with words denoting specific types of periodicals like `газета`, `журнал`

`Я подписался на новую газету` = `Я выписал новую газету`

BUT

`Я подписывался на новую газету` not always = `Я выписывал новую газету` as it depends on the meaning of `выписывал` as either `was setting up my subscription` OR `was a subscriber`, which transpires from the context

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае, слово **"выписать"** означает "отправить письмо с просьбой выслать следующий номер журнала". Это - старая модель распространения периодических изданий, когда для получения каждого номера надо заранее отправить письмо (и такие журналы существуют даже в 21м веке, если верить [бору](http://bash.im/quote/395598)).

Для случаев автоматической рассылки, когда не требуется запрашивать каждое сообщение - глагол "выписывать" не применим.

*Извиняюсь, что пишу по-русски, по-английски я писать не умею.*

Comment: a questionable response. when i was a subscriber i never sent any letters, as the subscription would usually be set up for a year, and imagine how many letters one would have to send being for instance a weekly newspaper subscriber, let alone of a more frequent periodical, in which case the letters wouldn't be able to reach the addressee fast enough either, so this doesn't make much sense, `выписать` means to set up a subscription for a certain period, which is only done once

Answer (score -1):

Do we really see difference between?

> Я подписался на это издание

and

> Я выписал это издание

No! It's the same. Depends on region etc.

But:

> To subscribe - Подписаться

not: `подписываться`

You never will use `подписываться` despite you can use it. And very rare you will use `выписать` in internet. `выписать` is quite usefull for paper magazine etc. `Я хочу выписать(подписаться на) эту газету. Я выписывал(подписывался на) журнал "Мурзилка". Пётр, выпиши(подпишись для меня на) мне(delete this word) газету "Правда"!` . For abstract words and internet we use 'подписаться'. `Я подписался на russian.stackexchange.com(internet). Я подпишусь на это издание(not concrete one).`.
And

> Subscription = подписка! NOT `выписка`!!!

So. Use `подписаться` as more universal word. No mistake.
`подписываться` - is little different actually.

> I didn't want to sign under this document- Я не хотел ПОДПИСЫВАТЬСЯ под этим документом.

I hope my english is not so worse and you can understand at least half.